# Проблема пониманием модели из 3d max формата fbx

Tags: opengl, fbx

У модели есть:

```
Vertices - точки 
PolygonVertexIndex - расположение точек
Edges -?
Normals - ?
NormalsW - ?
UV - точки на картинке
UVIndex -?
```

Comment: А документацию нашли? Normals - похоже что нормали. Edges - границы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Vertices** — вершины (отдельные точки в пространстве).
- **PolygonVertexIndex** — ссылочный индекс вершины. Применяется, когда вершины выносятся в отдельный список, а итоговый многогранник (модель то есть) образуется сборкой полигонов (как правило треугольников) из списка *ссылок на элементы списка вершин*. Преимущество заключается в том, что индекс (беззнаковое число) значительно меньше собственно вершины (структуры) по объёму, что уменьшает накладные расходы на многократное использование вершины при описании смежных полигонов.
- **Edges** — грани.
- **Normals** — нормали (перпендикуляры к поверхности).
- **UV** — координаты проекции вершины на плоскость текстуры.
- **UVIndex** — аналогично **PolygonVertexIndex**, только отделяются уже текстурные координаты. Позволяет использовать одну и ту же вершину в смежных гранях с несмежными UV-координатами.

Comment: Нужно добавить, что `Normals` и `NormalsW` отличаются скорее всего тем, что это нормали к поверхностям и к вершинам соответственно.

Comment: @Crantisz, откуда такая уверенность? Почему не наоборот? Может быть, `NormalsW` — это нормаль в мировой системе координат (`W` — World).

Comment: Возможно, я не знаю, просто предположил.